# What is the Java Stream way to use a different filtering (if any) on a collection, based on external conditions?

Tags: java, java-8

What is the **Java Stream** way to use different filtering (if any) on a collection, based on external conditions?

For example, I have an initial collection of elements:

`List<Data> initialData = ...`

And I want to filter them, in case of some additional external boolean condition:

`List<Data> data = something.isTrue() ? initialData.stream().filter() : initialData;`

Comment: `initialData.stream().filter(x -> something.isTrue() || yourActualCondition)` should work. Or just use an `if` and make it clear.

Comment: Encapsulate the external conditions (or the lack of them) into a `Predicate` and pass that to `filter()`.

Comment: @Kayaman can you please show me an example?

Comment: My understanding of _use different(!) filtering based on a condition_ is that you want to choose between filters. Your code suggests that you want to decide whether to filter. If that is the case then I'm not sure what you mean by _Java Stream way_

Answer (score 1):

Place the `Stream` processing into a dedicated method:

```
final <T> List<T> processStream( final Stream<T> initialData, final Predicate<T> predicate )
{
    return initialData.stream()
        .filter( predicate )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() );
}
```

This allows you to specify the filter according to your needs:

```
Predicate<Data> predicate = d -> true; // Initial predicate does no filtering
processStream( initialData, predicate );
```

or this:

```
predicate = predicate.and(d -> d.hasData()); // Chain additional conditions
processStream( initialData, predicate );
```

You have to wrap the processing into a method (or otherwise), because `predicate` needs to be a constant in the scope of the lambdas you use with the `Stream`.

And of course, the error handling (`null` checks) is missing …

Comment: I meant encapsulating the predicate creation in a separate method if it depends on external conditions. I would not create a method called `processStream` that is just a `filter()` on a stream, but rather the inverse `stream().filter(createPredicate())` way.

Answer (score 1):

A function that filters a list. As parameters the list, the field function, the comparison function and the comparison value.

What does such a function look like:

```
public <T, S> List<S> myFilter(List<S> from, Function<S, T> where, BiPredicate<T, T> predicate, T by) {
    return from.stream().filter(f -> predicate.test(where.apply(f), by)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Calling this function

```
List<Class> resultList = myFilter(sourceList, Class::getField, (a, b) -> a.equals(b), value);
```

Answer (score 1):

More of an addendum: keep in mind that using streams comes with a certain overhead. Yes, using it leads to nice, concise code (when you know what are doing), but there is runtime cost for establishing streams. From that point of view, it isn't necessarily always the "best" option to do things *inside* the stream.

Meaning: the given example isn't just about style. There might be a significant performance penalty for turning the external check into something that always streams your collection.